# Determine mdf size based on csv size for import

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert, mdf

I have a 148 gb csv file that I need to bulk import into a SQL Server table.  Is there a way to determine how much disk space I'll need for the mdf file growth?  I assume that the csv file isn't a 1 to 1 ratio as far as mdf file size, but honestly I just don't know.  I need to be able to ask my sysadmin for enough space without going overboard :)

Thanks!

-emo

Comment: Nope. At least not for us across the internet. We don't know how many columns, the column datatypes, etc. Since you do, you could get a rough estimate by doing the math on the datatype, number of rows, etc.

Comment: Emo, it's your job to go overboard - it's your sysadmin's job to say "no" :)  Kidding aside, I would copy ten thousand randomly-selected rows of the CSV into a separate file, import them, and then see how big the resulting table is.  Repeat a few times and take an average.  Should get you close.  Don't forget to allow for table growth due to normal operations.

Comment: It's *unlikely* to be as large, but then, that also depends on the indexes you build on the table afterwards. Considering the size, I **assume** that you're going to be indexing the table afterwards if you want any kind of performance against it. Without knowing any details of your table, that could involve several indexes, which will increase the size of the table/database you insert the data into. Theoretically, you *could* end up with a table (including indexes, etc) that is larger than your CSV, however, that is very unlikely and would likely require poor data type choices too.